# How to parse text to html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am currently using an api that gives text with html tags in them like

```
"<a href="http://dog.running">the dog ran</a>"
```

please how do i parse this so on my web page so that i can get the string to work like an actual html tag.
i have tried using dom parser, but it gives the whole html structure, starting form

```
<html><body><the actual tag><body><html>.
```

any help will be useful, thanks

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML = "<a href="http://dog.running">the dog ran</a>"`

Comment: I don't really understand the question... are you trying to find that element in the HTML, or trying to insert your tag somewhere inside the HTML.

Comment: Are you using any libraries like jQuery or frameworks like Angular ? It's not usually not a good idea to render the HTML received from server as it is not safe (could be a vector for XSS attacks) unless we're very sure that HTML is generated completely on the server side without blindly passing what the end user has posted.

Comment: im using react, and im trying to make the string "<a href="link">Link</a>" actually act like link on my html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DBankx  Try This

```
var your_html_element = parseHTML("<a href='http://dog.running'>the dog ran</a>");
//you can append this element in your html page.

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(your_html_element);

function parseHTML(html) {
    var t = document.createElement('template');
    t.innerHTML = html;
    return t.content.cloneNode(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your API will never return a correct HTML structure made of html, head and body tags, you can just treat any child of the `<body>` from you parsed doc as your resulting DOM:

```js
const the_data = `<a href="http://dog.running">the dog ran</a>`;
const parsed_doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString( the_data, "text/html" );
const resulting_nodes = [ ...parsed_doc.body.childNodes ];
console.log( resulting_nodes ); // [<a href="http://dog.running">the dog ran</a>]
```

But beware, as soon as you will adopt any of these nodes by the current document, you will expose yourself to XSS attacks:

```js
const the_data = `<img src="" onerror="alert('am bad')">`;
const parsed_doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString( the_data, "text/html" );
const resulting_nodes = [ ...parsed_doc.body.childNodes ];

document.body.append( ...resulting_nodes );
```